# How do I remove the blank spaces before a certain character using notepad++

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, find-and-replace

I want to remove the spaces before the ".V" if posible.  How do I do that with the replace feature in Notepad ++
For Example, I want this:

```
A   .V  Armor Minerals Inc
AAC-P   .V  Anacott Acquisition Corporation
AAG .V  Aftermath Silver Ltd
AAN .V  Aton Resources Inc
AAT .V  Ati Airtest Technologies Inc
AAU .V  Angold Resources Ltd
```

to look like this:

```
A.V Armor Minerals Inc
AAC-P.V Anacott Acquisition Corporation
AAG.V   Aftermath Silver Ltd
AAN.V   Aton Resources Inc
AAT.V   Ati Airtest Technologies Inc
AAU.V   Angold Resources Ltd
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (but probably not bullet  proof is Find&Replace

Search for  `.V` and replace with `.V` and tick match case
for certain cases
you may even search (from your examples given) for `.V` to get better hits

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one space before the `.V`, then using @alfetta's answer is the way to go. If there are one or more spaces before it, then you can try the following:

- Find what : `\s+(\.V)`
- Replace with : `$1`
- Search mode : Regular expression

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+(?=\.v)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?=\.v)         # positive lookahead, make sure we have .v after the spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]